# Spark-submit with uber-jar failed to execute the job without any output or error logs

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lstm, spark-submit, deeplearning4j

I am trying to generate uber-jar using `sbt` compile and `sbt` package commands for running my application on our remote server with spark installed as standalone mode there. I used deeplearning4j framework for building LSTM neural network and tend to perform training model through spark. Nevertheless, I got into an issue when running the spark-submit command:

```
spark-submit --class "lstm.SparkLSTM" --master local[*] 
stock_prediction_scala_2.11-0.1.jar --packages 
org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.9.1 "/home/hadoop/ScalaWorkspace/Stock_Prediction_Scala/target/lstm_train/prices-split-adjusted.csv" "WLTW"
```

The problem is that seemly spark-submit did not take effect in my circumstance. It has been terminated right after entering spark-submit without throwing any errors. I have not seen the progress of training in the output.

```
[hadoop@abc lstm_train]$ spark-submit --class "lstm.SparkLSTM" --master local[*] stock_prediction_scala_2.11-0.1.jar --packages org.deeplearning4j:deeplearning4j-core:0.9.1 "/home/hadoop/ScalaWorkspace/Stock_Prediction_Scala/target/lstm_train/prices-split-adjusted.csv" "WLTW"
2018-04-25 17:06:50 WARN  Utils:66 - Your hostname, gaion34 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.0.173 instead (on interface eno1)
2018-04-25 17:06:50 WARN  Utils:66 - Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
2018-04-25 17:06:51 WARN  NativeCodeLoader:62 - Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
2018-04-25 17:06:51 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Shutdown hook called
2018-04-25 17:06:51 INFO  ShutdownHookManager:54 - Deleting directory /tmp/spark-c4aee15e-d23b-4c03-95a7-12d9d39f714a
```

my main class:
https://gist.github.com/rickyhai11/627d0da8bc93615785382b249618f43b

How to see generated logs by spark-submit command? I have tried to use --verbose, however, it did not help.

Any one has experienced this issue before, please advise me . thanks

Comment: Try play with spark-submit options, I would suspect you need to use: --deploy-mode=client -> https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html

Comment: @rickyhai11 - Can you please help with the resolutions. Even I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

> How to see generated logs by spark-submit command? I have tried to use --verbose, however, it did not help.

See web UI on port 8080, more details [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/spark-standalone.html#monitoring-and-logging)

Since you mentioned "remote server", this UI may not be accessible in your local browser at localhost:8080. You'll need [port forwarding with ssh tunneling](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example#sec-What-Is-SSH-Port-Forwarding-aka-SSH-Tunneling).

Additionally:

Option --files will make sure that your .csv is uploaded to the working directory of each executor

Make sure the .jar is indeed present at ./ By default, `sbt package` creates the uber jar at `target/scala-2.11/`

I'd drop the quotes from class name